# Is there any System API in linux to provide Atomic Write operation to files

Tags: c#, c, linux, filesystems, atomic

Motive is to provide atomcity to important file, like if these files are under write operation (e.g of 20 kb) and in between power goes off then no new data MUST get written to the original file.Thus my original file will be  safe (not corrupted).

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice world, where we write to or delete data from files while there's no power.

Comment: I think what you or your admin are actually looking for is an UPS (uninterruptible power supply). There is no way to achieve what you want by software, it's a hardware issue. The UPS can supply power for a short time if the main power switches off, and it tells the servers to shut down, so that the processes currently running can go to a safe state (writing data to files and closing them appropriatly).

Comment: And while there are software approaches that mitigate the risk of corruption they all still rely on the hardware telling the truth which more often than not is not the case

Answer (score 2):

This is what [*journalling filesystems*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) do. However, this is very expensive, since all data has to be written twice.

Because it is so expensive, most journalling filesystems actually do *not* journal data writes, only metadata writes. Therefore, on most journalling filesystems, the filesystem structure is protected from corruption and inconsistencies, but the file contents are not.

The [Ext4 filesystem](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/) supports full data journalling, although metadata-only journalling is the default.

[*Log-structured filesystems*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system) are a (conceptual) extension to journalling filesystems, where there is *only* the journal.

*Copy-On-Write filesystems* provide the same guarantees as journalling filesystems.

[*Soft Updates*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_updates) and [*Write-Ahead Physical Block Logging*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_Ahead_Physical_Block_Logging) provide the same guarantees as metadata-only journalling filesystems.

Of course, a disk controller with battery-backup and an [Uninterruptible Power Supply](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) may also be a good idea.